# Images with display: flex; displaying wrong on chrome, work in firefox

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, cross-browser

I am working on a website..
Using

```
display: flex;
```

The problem is in Chrome the pictures and videos are stretched and in Firefox they perfect..

I have validated my HTML and CSS and there was no problems...

Any who got some suggestions that i can try out?

I have tried placing flex on the images and videos itself and i have been using

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

and

```
flex: 0 1 auto;
```

I have tried width, and haven't touched the height

```
#section-campaign {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 100%;
}
   .campaign-thumbnails {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .campaign-thumbnails img {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

 <section id="section-campaign">
        <div class="campaign-title">
            <h3>Choose campaign</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="campaign-thumbnails">
            <img id="campaign-img-q" onmouseout="qFilterOn()" onmouseover="qNoFilter()" onclick="qFilter()" class="thumbnail-campaign grey-campaign-img" src="images/city.jpeg"
                 alt="campaign 1">
            <img id="campaign-img" onmouseout="filterOn()" onmouseover="noFilter()" onclick="xFilter()" class="thumbnail-campaign grey-campaign-img" src="images/resort.jpeg"
                 alt="campaign 2">
            <img id="campaign-img-z" onmouseout="zFilterOn()" onmouseover="zNoFilter()" onclick="zFilter()" class="thumbnail-campaign grey-campaign-img" src="images/culture.jpeg"
                 alt="campaign 3">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here you see the HTML markup, and the CSS linked together with this Section

Comment: did you try Ctrl+F5, just incase chrome cached deeply (happens to me quite often to not load up new updated CSS)?

Comment: Yes i have done that

Comment: add vendor prefix

Comment: I think maybe its the pictures and videos since the vendor prefixes aint working either

Comment: Post your markup and css for the issue and demonstrate it in http://jsfiddle.net if you can. With the given info, we can only guess what's going on. It sounds like some simple problem, if you posted your code it would of been solved already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are direct children of the flex container, I would set `flex: 0 0 auto;` for the images and videos, since you don't want them to grow or shrink (and if not done yet, set the images `height` to `auto`)